# Compare 2 git repositoris in detached head state

Tags: git

So I have 2 repositories where the git checkout is done by the commit id and the HEAD is pointing to commit hash directly.

How to check if the checked out files are same or not.
Tried using git diff by adding the other repo as a remote and diff from current HEAD's commit hash to the other commit hash.

Comment: These are 2 different repos with different history?

Comment: That's how you should do it. Why do you doubt it is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

If both repositories are in `clean` status, you can test if the two heads reference to the same tree object. To get the tree object of `HEAD`,

```
git log -1 HEAD --pretty=%T
# or
git rev-parse HEAD^{tree}
```

However, there are some cases where the checked-out files are not always the same with those in the commit even if the status is "clean".

1. In one repository a file has been modified and the "assume unchanged" or "skip worktree" bit has been set on the file. The repository is reported to be "clean" but it's not really clean. The two heads point to the same tree object, but their checked-out files are not the same.
2. The two sets of checked-out files have exactly the same contents. One file is not executable in one repository and its counterpart in the other repository is executable. The two tree objects are definitely different.
3. Different "smudge" filter commands are enabled in the 2 repositories. If so, when the same tree object is checked out, the files could have different contents.
4. Some git configurations may affect the line endings and white spaces.

There might be other exceptions. But they are not very common. If you think these rare cases can be ignored, to compare the 2 tree objects is the most straight-forward method.

If the repositories are not "clean", a comparing tool is recommended.